# Cannot acess to a local database via R

Tags: r, database, database-connection

I am trying to access to a database `HWSD.md` which can be downloaded here : http://webarchive.iiasa.ac.at/Research/LUC/External-World-soil-database/HTML/HWSD_Data.html?sb=4

I have a linux machine and I tried this command line but I have a message error

```
require(MonetDB.R)
Mydb <- src_monetdb("*/HWSD.mdb")
Error in socketConnection(host = host, port = port, blocking = TRUE, open = "r+b",  : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In socketConnection(host = host, port = port, blocking = TRUE, open = "r+b",  :
  localhost:50000 cannot be opened
```

Anyone can help me out with it?

Comment: I don't see any description of how you installed MonetDB.

Comment: Well in R, you need to use the function `install.packages(MonetDB.R)` and then `require (MonetDB.R)`